# Get dynamic id on button click in dialog box

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have some products. I am getting feedback from user against each product. When User clicks on "Reply" button for feedback, A dialog box appears.

Now, the problem is that, each time "Reply" button opens the dialog against same id. To make sure, i am printing Id in dialog box that returns same id each time...
I want to let the dialog open but with different id.

How can i do that ?

In this way i am getting id of product:

```
$get_product = "select * from product_reviwes where product_code = '$pro_code' ORDER BY user_reply_date DESC";
```

The code is this:

```
$a = strtolower($product_owner);
$b = strtolower($email);

if($a == $b){
    echo "<br>
            <small><div align='center'><a href='#login-box' class='login-window'>Reply</a></div></small>
            <hr>
            <div id='login-box' class='login-popup'>
              <a href='#' class='close'><img src='images/close_pop.png' class='btn_close' title='Close Window' alt='Close' /></a>
              <form method='post' class='signin' action='$url&ID1=$ID'>
                <fieldset class='textbox'>
                    <label class='username'>
                        <span>Please Enter Your Reply</span>
                        <input id='reply' name='reply' value='' type='text' autocomplete='on' placeholder='Please Enter Your Reply Maximum 1000 Letters' maxlength='1000'>
                    </label>
                    <br>
                    this is ID  =   $ID;//  testing to see id 

                    <br>
                    <button class='submit button1' type='submit' name='post'>Reply</button>
                </fieldset>
              </form>
            </div>";
}
```

if i change
href='#login-box' 
with
href='$url&ID1=$ID'

then it picks desired id but the dialog-box does not open

Comment: Was the above code inside a loop and are you getting dynamic values for $url and $ID

Comment: @Sasikumarhx
yeah that's running in while loop

Comment: @Sasikumarhx
see my updated answer

Answer (score -1):

Try this method

```
<div id='login-box-<?=$ID;?>' class='login-popup'>
```

And while clicking the Reply button show the respective login-box div based on the ID

```
<button class='submit button1' type='button' onclick='$("#login-box-<?=$ID;?>").show()' name='post'>Reply</button>
```

Comment: should i change the type = 'submit' to type = 'button'?

Comment: Your code is not opening the dialog box now on click reply button

Comment: keep the submit button and call the function in onsubmit in form

Comment: 1) dialog-box not opening. 2) on hover over reply button, it started showing the desired id(the id you are going to reply to).